# Comprobar formato Telefono - Eventos Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, eventos, function

Pues bien, a la hora de comprobar un número de este formulario, el teléfono tiene que ser 9 números (en el cual se permiten espacios o guiones; pero se eliminarán antes de enviar el formulario) No se como enfocar esta última parte y necesito ayuda.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit=comprobarTodo;
}


function comprobarNombre(){
 var formulario=document.getElementById('form1');
 var inputs=formulario.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var nombre=inputs[0].value;

   var nombres=nombre.split("");
   
   if((nombres.length>0) && (nombres.length<=30)){
    return true;
   }else{
    alert('Error. El nombre es incorrecto');
   }
}

function comprobarApellido(){
 var formulario=document.getElementById('form1');
 var inputs=formulario.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var apellido=inputs[1].value;

 var apellidos=apellido.split("");

 if((apellidos.length>0) && (apellidos.length<=100)){
  return true;
 }else{
  alert('Error. Apellido incorrecto');
 }
}

function comprobarTelefono(){
 var formulario=document.getElementById('form1');
 var inputs=formulario.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var telefono=inputs[2].value;

 var tlf=telefono.split("");
 
}  

function comprobarTodo(){
 comprobarNombre();
 comprobarApellido();
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="POST">
 <label>Nombre</label> 
 <input type="text" name="nombre">
 <br><br>
 <label>Apellido</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellido">
 <br><br>
 <label>Telefono</label>
 <input type="text" name="telefono">
 <br><br>
 <label>Email</label>
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <br><br>
 <input id="boton" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
 <input id="boton2" type="reset" name="reset" value="Restablecer">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando expresiones regulares y el método `.replace()` podés reemplazar todo texto que no fuera un número. Por ejemplo:

```
"12303-023.03 231".replace(/\D+/g, "");
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```js
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit=comprobarTodo;
}


function comprobarNombre(){
 var formulario=document.getElementById('form1');
 var inputs=formulario.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var nombre=inputs[0].value;

   var nombres=nombre.split("");
   
   if((nombres.length>0) && (nombres.length<=30)){
    return true;
   }else{
    alert('Error. El nombre es incorrecto');
   }
}

function comprobarApellido(){
 var formulario=document.getElementById('form1');
 var inputs=formulario.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var apellido=inputs[1].value;

 var apellidos=apellido.split("");

 if((apellidos.length>0) && (apellidos.length<=100)){
  return true;
 }else{
  alert('Error. Apellido incorrecto');
 }
}

function comprobarTelefono(){
 var formulario=document.getElementById('form1');
 var inputs=formulario.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var telefono=inputs[2].value;
  
 // reemplazo todo texto que no sea un número
 var tlf=telefono.replace(/\D+/g, "");
 
}  

function comprobarTodo(){
 comprobarNombre();
 comprobarApellido();
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="POST">
 <label>Nombre</label> 
 <input type="text" name="nombre">
 <br><br>
 <label>Apellido</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellido">
 <br><br>
 <label>Telefono</label>
 <input type="text" name="telefono">
 <br><br>
 <label>Email</label>
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <br><br>
 <input id="boton" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
 <input id="boton2" type="reset" name="reset" value="Restablecer">
</form>
```

Comment: Está muy bien planteado Kleith, gracias. Me gustaría saber también otra combinación en la cual no se use expresión regular, si es posible.

Comment: Por qué? Qué es lo que necesitás hacer como para no utilizar expresiones regulares? Otra posibilidad es reemplazar caracter por caracter.

Comment: Me piden en el enunciado no emplearlas, seguiré peleándome con lo poco que queda.

Comment: Podés separar el `string` letra por letra, con `.substring()`, y compararla con los números, y si coincide entonces se guarda en una nueva variable.